# Pack boost into shared library

Tags: c++, boost, linker, dependencies

I'm trying to compile some code with boost dependencies that I want to use as a dynamic shared library, but without any boost dependency (no boost installation as a requirement). How eaxctly do I go about it?

I'm compiling my code with:

```
g++ -Wall -fPIC -o myclass.o -c myclass.cpp 
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,myclass.so.1 -o lib/myclass.so.1 myclass.o -lc
```

however, the built library shows a couple of boost dependencies, as

```
ldd lib/myclass.so.1
```

produces the output:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffda9df000)
libboost_system.so.1.60.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.60.0 (0x00007f934e776000)
libboost_serialization.so.1.60.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_serialization.so.1.60.0 (0x00007f934e538000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f934e1b6000)
libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f934deb0000)
libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f934db0f000)
/usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055802a452000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f934d8f9000)
librt.so.1 => /usr/lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007f934d6f0000)
libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f934d4d3000)
```

What must I change on the `g++` call to pack all the boost dependencies into the .so file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just "stuff" one .so inside another .so. You need to link with static libraries, instead of shared libraries.

Most Linux distributions include an optional "development" subpackage that includes statically-linked versions of shared libraries.

You will have to install that package, and then completely change how you link your own library. Instead of, for example, linking with

```
-lboost_system
```

you will have to replace this with an explicit link against "/usr/lib64/libboost_system.a", or wherever libboost_system.a is installed. Lather, rinse, repeat, and not just for the boost libraries you link with directly, but with all other boost libraries that those libraries themselves link with, etc...

Consult your Linux distribution's documentation for information where and how the statically-linked versions of shared libraries are packaged.

Comment: I compiled boost from source, and have the static libraries on the same directory, so it's just changin the makefile.